# Использование JavaScript для установки пароля для страницы

Tags: javascript, html, alert, prompt

Использую данный код для установки пароля для страницы:

```js
pass = prompt('Владелец файла установил пароль на просмотр данного материала. Введите пароль.');
if (pass == '$OTHER3$') alert('Пароль верный.');
else {
  alert('Пароль не верный, покиньте страницу.');
  top.location.href = "";
}
```

Скрипт отлично работает и выполняет свою функцию, если в браузере включен JS. Если же он отключен, то пользователь свободно входит на страницу (ввод пароля игнорируется).

Как усовершенствовать этот код и заставить его использовать JS для надежной защиты страницы? Подскажите правильное решение этой проблемы.

Comment: Если JS отключен - никакой код выполняться не будет. Т.о. нужно менять сам html...
Или скрыть его "исполняемую" часть. А скриптом (если он включен) приводить html в нужный вид.

Comment: Или переведите ваш код на какой нибудь фреймворк - react, angular, vue. Тогда при отключенном javaScript вообще ничего работать не будет :) А у вас, как я понимаю, даже с включенным JS сайт можно "хакнуть", просто по F12 вытащить HTML и стили + js, убрав оттуда данную проверку

Comment: @SwaD, убрать проверку намного сложнее чем просто посмотреть пароль

Comment: @Grundy Ну если он там так в явном виде вписан, то да )

Comment: А что мешает выдавать промежуточную html страницу с запросом пароля?

Comment: "Надёжной" защита только на JS не будет. Т.к. всё просчитывается на клиенте – возможно подсмотреть пароль или вообще отключить проверку.